# Change multiple rows PostgeSQL

Tags: sql, excel, database, postgresql

I like to change Multiple rows in a PostgreSQL database. I've got an Excel file, which I like to turn a query (or maybe there is another faster way).

For example:

I have column1 401,402,403 which are codes for packing material, they have different prices.

```
code   price
401    0,31
402    0,32
403    0,33
```

These prices changes, so I have 2 columns in excel with the changes, one column with the code and one with the new price. The table contains 619 rows, where 153 are going to change. To speed up things I like to change them all at once.

Already find a solution, using a case command (see below), but that doesn't work out for me.

```
Update "Table"
set price= (case
when code=  '401'   then    '0.33'
when code=  '402'   then    '0.34'
when code=  '403'   then    '0.35'end)
where code in('401','402','403')
```

When I use this way, I can't use the **''** in the query (for the price). When I leave them out, the price column turn into 0

Comment: The `UPDATE` with the `CASE` should work, if you fix the syntax issues (missing a `)` or a `(` too much). To demonstrate the problem [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Just wondering, but maybe the problem is the decimal separator? In your example data you use comma, and in your query you use dot. ¿How is the data stored in your Excel? Maybe is a format issue and that would explain why removing the '' the price turn into 0 (integer field maybe?)

Comment: Think my way of convert was wrong. changed the query to update fust
set fustprijs = case
when FUSTCOD=  '401' then 0.33
when FUSTCOD=  '402' then 0.33
when FUSTCOD=  '403' then 0.35 end
where fustcod in('401','402','403') 

it works now, just tested it with 3 rules, the where clause I type by hand. 
Wonder if it's possible to get a proper query out of Excel automatically, any advise? Excel contains of 2 columns, one for the code (A) and one for the price (B)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by creating an individual update statement for each row. Suppose that you have the "code" and "price" info in column C and D and in column E enter the following formula:

```
= "Update Table Price=" &D4& " WHERE code=" & C4 & ";"
```

Then copy column E with only "values" options and run the statements in postgre

the result should be as following

```
Update Table Price=0,31 WHERE code=401;
Update Table Price=0,32 WHERE code=402;
Update Table Price=0,33 WHERE code=403;
```

Comment: The excel part works, but I cant "run" the statement in Postgre. I can use SQL only.

Comment: "Set" was missing in the answer, Update Table Set Price=0,31 WHERE code=401;

Comment: I tried, 1 single command works. When I add a second line, it doesn't work. I separate them bij a ; mark. But I think that is where he gets stuck.

Comment: replace the comma "," with period "." as decimal seperator and it should work Update Table Price=0.31 WHERE code=401;
Update Table Price=0.32 WHERE code=402;
Update Table Price=0.33 WHERE code=403;

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Update "Table"
set price= (case
when code=  '401'   then    '0.33'
when code=  '402'   then    '0.34'
when code=  '403'   then    '0.35' 
else price end);
```